# Creating my own std::vector in C program

Tags: c++, c, vector

I know how to code with C++, however this is my first time I try to use C.

I even tried to define a cVector.h and cVector.c in order to implement some of the std::vector functionality. but when I compile my code I receive the following error.

Here is same of the code:

cVector.h

```
#define VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY 520

typedef struct {
  int size;      // slots used so far
  int capacity;  // total available slots
  int *data;     // array of integers we're storing
} Vector;

void vector_init( Vector *vector);
```

cVector.c

```
#include "cVector.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void vector_init(Vector *vector) {
  // initialize size and capacity
  vector->size = 0;
  vector->capacity = VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY;

  // allocate memory for vector->data
  vector->data = malloc(sizeof(int) * vector->capacity);
}
```

here is the usage:

```
#include "cVector.h" 

Vector times; 
vector_init(&times);

int main{
....}
```

and finally error:

```
Ser.c:135:13: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
```

Comment: "Is there any way to use std::vector in C program?" No, but you can implement something similar, which is what you are trying to do. Why is `vector_init` an inline function?

Comment: You're not really showing us enough of Ser.c, which is where the error occurs. Please present a [complete, minimal testcase](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call a function at file scope like that. You need to move the call into a function (e.g. `main`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a function outside the declaration of another function. Btw you can declare variables as globals variables but the line
`vector_init(&times);`
must be written inside of the main function.
If you are interested the gcc's error message it's because of he is trying to find the declaration of a new function, this is, the name of a type or ... instead.